# Soundcloud and api rate limits

Tags: api, soundcloud

What are current api rate limits for track liking? According to  [documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits) the only enforced limits are for stream playing api.

> Global Rate Limit
>
> We currently do not enforce any limit on the total number of calls made by a client application in aggregate.

I'm receiving following response when trying to like track via `PUT /me/favorites/track` endpoint:

```
{
  "errors": [{
     "warning_level": "info",
     "reason_phrase": "info: too many likes",
     "release_at": "2016-08-03T12:20:38+00:00",
     "acknowledge_url": "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/warning/favoriting"
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I wrong or public documentation is inaccurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you liking the same track? Though there is probably not API rate limits, there is most likely a limit on how many times a user can like a track, to prevent false counts.

Are you liking different tracks? This may be to prevent bots from artificially liking tracks - they want likes to be manual by a user.

Both wouldn't count as rate limits, so I'm not surprised they're not in the API documentation.

This is to prevent fake fan likes aka 'number juicing'. See

http://5chicago.com/features/how-to-become-a-fake-soundcloud-superstar/

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-stop-insincere-fake-liking-musician-bots-from-invading-my-tracks-on-Soundcloud